# add_to() in Pods Wordpress doesn't work

Tags: php, wordpress, podscms

I'm trying to use add_to() in the latest version of Pods (2.3.18) and it doesn't seems to be creating the relationship in the database table (wp_postmeta). What I'm doing is:

```
$postPod = pods("post", $post_id);

$postPod->add_to("field", "valueID");
```

But the meta_key "field" doesn't appear in the database table.

How can I properly use this add_to function? I didn't find any examples in the documentation.

Comment: Add_to should return the value of the post it was added to. Please check that it returns the correct ID, which it should, presuming  $post_id was set properly.

Comment: @JPollock It does. It seems that the function is not doing anything... How can I check if it does? Which database table is holding this information? Because in wp_postmeta I can't find it.

Comment: This article explains how relationship fields are stored http://pods.io/docs/database-reference/database-storage-relationship-fields/ You should check if add_to is creating new posts. If so that means that $pods_id does not have the right ID in it, as add_to will create a new item if the ID its trying to add to doesn't exist.